# AMP in a dynamically generated classifieds sites

Tags: html, amp-html

I'm working with a client that is trying to build their mobile site using AMP.  The site is an auto classifieds site.  The content is updated constantly as new inventory is added and sold, etc. Also these sites generate millions of pages with strings for brand, year, etc. which are tens of possibilities, etc.

How can we accomplish that the content on the site remains fresh if Google is caching the data?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you read AMP documentation on how Google handles cache?

Comment: What's your concern here? The sheer amount of pages or that content might get stale on the cache?